How to prove this graph doesn't have a Hamiltonian cycle?
How do I prove this graph doesn't have a Hamiltonian cycle? By looking into the graph, I see that if my starting point is $a$ and then I move to $b$ and then let's suppose that I visit every vertex under $a,b,d$. When I reach vertex $d$, if I move to $c$ (which is the last vertex left to visit), then that would leave me with not way to get back to $a$ and complete the cycle. Of course, this reasoning is not good enough to say this graph doesn't have a Hamiltonian cycle. I hope you can help me guys with this. Thanks!


Doesn't take a lot to make your idea into a full argument: Assume the graph has a Hamiltonian cycle. This cycle must contain the edges $a$-$b$ and $a$-$d$ since they are the only edges meeting $a$, and it must contain $b$-$c$ and $c$-$d$ for the same reason. But these four edges already form a cycle, oops! ...whence no Hamiltonian cycle exists.

Thanks for answering. By the way, what you said is what the solution guide told me too, that the four edges already form a cycle, but still I don't get why those edges being a cycle implies it can't be Hamiltonian.

@Álvaro A Hamiltonian cycle contains exactly two edges incident to each node (essentially by definition). Thus, if you already have a cycle, you cannot extend it to a Hamiltonian cycle: There's no way to "escape" the cycle you already have since it already contains at least two edges incident to each node.
